# How to get network download speed when playing m3u8/online files?

Tags: c#, uwp, media-player

I'm using `MediaPlayerElement` playing m3u8/online files.
How to get the network speed?

Comment: Maybe [MediaPlayer Adaptive streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/adaptive-streaming) holds some clues. There's DownloadBitrate mentioned as well as Diagonstics that may offer what you need.

Comment: Seems a good way, I'll try.